# Python - CV, contour and measurements

Tags: image-processing, python, opencv, measurement, camera

I have small problem with cv in Python and rhombus. I can read frame from the camera and create contours...

```
img_BW = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(img_BW, TR, 200, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
cv2.imshow("ThreshPaint", thresh)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(image=thresh, mode=cv2.RETR_TREE,method=cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

#edged = cv2.Canny(img_BW, 30, 200)
#cv2.imshow("Canny", edged)

cv2.drawContours(image=frame, contours=contours, contourIdx=0, color=(0, 0, 255), thickness=2, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)
cv2.imshow("Contours", frame)
```

and I see rhombus with contours. I know how to get coordinates of the points A,B,C,D measure distance between them but how to check distance between point A and X which is on the contour? the measure-line must be perpendicular to the point A.[image]